# Integrate sass in angular template visual tudio

Tags: sass, webpack, angular-template

I am using angular2 template install in visual studio (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack) for my project. I want to intergrate SASS but it throw exception "**Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined**".

This my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] }
        ]
    }
};
```

and `home.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./home.component.scss')]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with the same issue few days ago.
I was able to fix this by regenerating .net core app using yoman generator. It has the same template as the template pack but with newer packages.

```
npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa
yo aspnetcore-spa
```

Then I Installed all dependencies

```
npm install node-sass sass-loader raw-loader --save
```

Edited webpack.config module loaders

```
{ test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
```

Added scss file to component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'counter',
    templateUrl: './counter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./counter.component.scss']

})
```

Created counter.component.scss

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #ff0000;

p {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```